# Why this XML is valid?

Tags: xml

I checked in several validators this xml:

```
<root>
  <tag>text</tag>even more text
</root>
```

It is valid. Can somebody please explain what is "even more text" String from example, and maybe refer me to some docs.

Comment: post the list of validators you used?

Comment: emeraldjava, 1) http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp , 2) http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xml-validator.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a piece of [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) (just like the other piece of text inside the tag element).

Unless a DTD/Schema/etc says otherwise, any element may contain character data.