# Benefits of XML character data outside of tag

Tags: xml

This question is based on my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967880/why-this-xml-is-valid).

I belive we are all used that data in xml is located between tags, like:

```
<root>
  <tag>useful text</tag>
</root>
```

But following xml is also valid:

```
<root>
  <tag>useful text</tag> more text
</root>
```

Usually you don't see this too often in real life. Can you please give me several examples of usage and benefits which this xml's feature gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without this things such as [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) wouldn't be possible.

A complete valid XHTML example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head><title>Zebra</title></head>
   <body>
     <div><h1><em>useful</em> text more text</h1></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```